# how can i use aggregation in logstash-elasticsearch filter plugin

Tags: logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, logstash-configuration

```
if[type] == "mytype"    {       elasticsearch       {
                hosts => ["192.168.1.1:9200"]
                index => "my_index"
                query_template => "/logstash/my_query.json"
                 aggregation_fields => 
                 {
                 "seqnumber" => "find_seqnumber"
                 }
          }
    }
```

**why return this error for me ?? ::**

> Unknown setting 'aggregation_fields' for elasticsearch

**in logstash log**

Comment: I think you are looking for [Aggregate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**here is the answer link :**

the issue solved by elasticsearch filter plugin versions

**https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-can-i-use-aggregation-in-logstash-elasticsearch-filter-plugin/133805/5**